# Simplifying a probability distribution function using an exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

I have a *pdf* for a variable $r$ given two other variables $m, \kappa$ defined as follows:

\begin{align}
p(r|m,\kappa)=\frac{I_0(\kappa r)}{I_0(\kappa)^m}r\psi_m(r),
\end{align}

where $\psi_m(r)$ is some function (not important), and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind with order 0 (also not important).

I'm reading code written by the dude who defined this *pdf*, but in his code he uses the following equation for it:

\begin{align}
p(r|m,\kappa)=e^{I_0(\kappa r) - mI_0(\kappa)}r\psi_m(r).
\end{align}

In his code, he then divides the whole function (across all $r$) by its sum.

Can anyone shed some light on how these two forms of the *pdf* match up?

Comment: $\psi_m(r)$ IS important because it depends on $r$ and it looks like you (or the dude) are missing $\log$ in front of $I_0$'s in the exponent.

Comment: Is this the correct interpretation?

\begin{equation}
p(r \mid m,\kappa) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{I_0(\kappa r) - m I_0(\kappa)} r \psi_m(r)}{\sum_r \mathrm{e}^{I_0(\kappa r) - m I_0(\kappa)} r \psi_m(r)}
\end{equation}

Comment: @A.S. i guess the question is whether the $\log$ changes the relative probabilities.  i don't see how the definition of $\psi_m$ is important to the logic of this simplification.  $\psi_m$ does not change moving from one version of the equation to the other.

Comment: @Ritz yes it is.

Comment: Of course the log changes relative probabilities. $A/B$ doesn't scale as $e^A/e^B=e^{A-B}$ does.

Comment: @A.S. just for clarity here, the theory that the author left out $\log$ doesn't make sense.  the author would not have added in manipulations of his variables that cancel each other out (do $e^{\log(x)}$ just for fun).  one should interpret this question as the author having done something to make the computation of his function in software more efficient.

Comment: Imagine that computing $I_0$ is difficult because it's really large. But you only need their ratio. so you compute $A/B=\exp(\ln A-\ln B)$ avoiding dealing with large numbers and "reducing" the ratio of these quantities ($\frac {A/B}{C/D}$) to subtraction.

Comment: $\log a^b=b\log a$

Comment: the conclusion here is that @A.S. was correct with his first comment.  what i thought was the modified bessel in the code was actually the log of the modified bessel.